# fstream is writing on file against an if else statement

Tags: c++

I have a file named "password.txt" which has 2 rows of usernames and passwords

2 string vectors named, user & password

This function uses a new username and password and checks if the username already exists in the user vector using a for loop

If it does exist, it breaks out of the loop
If it does not exist, it will add the username and password to the vectors and write them both on the file

```
void PasswordFile::addpw(string newuser, string newpassword) {
    fstream file;
    file.open("password.txt", ios::app);
    
    //if the vectors is empty it automatically adds a new user
    //is working
    if (user.size() < 1){
        user.push_back(newuser);
        password.push_back(newpassword);
        file << newuser << " " << newpassword << "\r";
    }

    //the loop (is not working)

    for (int i=0; i < user.size(); i++){
        string name = user[i];
        if (name == newuser) {
            break;
        } //it shouldn't continue past this point if the name is in the vector but it does

        else {
            cout << newuser;
            cout << " is being written onto the file\n";
            user.push_back(newuser);
            password.push_back(newpassword);
            file << newuser << " " << newpassword << "\r";
        }
    }
    
    file.close();
}
```

the problem is that it is writing the second name twice and the third name three times

I know also that it is pushing the newuser and newpassword multiple times onto the vector, but I can't figure out where or why its looping more than it should or why its ignoring the break and writing onto the file anyway

"password.txt" 1 run

```
dbotting 123qwe
egomez qwerty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
```

"password.txt" second run

```
dbotting 123qwe
egomez qwerty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
egomez qwerty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
```

it keeps adding the last 2 every time its run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WHILE* you are looping through the `user` vector, any time you encounter an entry that does not match the `newuser` being searched for, you are writing the `newuser`/`newpassword` to the file and pushing them into the vectors <sup>1</sup> (which then affects subsequent iterations of your loop), and then you move on to the next entry.

So, for example, if you start with a file like:

```
dbotting 123qwe
egomez qwerty
```

`tongyu` does not match `dbotting`, so you add `tongyu`.  And then `tongyu` does not match `egomez`, so you add `tongyu` again.  So you end up with:

```
dbotting 123qwe
egomez qwerty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
```

And then on the next run, `tongyu` doesn't match `dbotting` or `egomez`, so you add `tongyu` twice again. But then it does match `tongyu`, so you don't add it again, and break the loop.   So you end up with:

```
dbotting 123qwe
egomez qwerty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
tongyu liberty
```

And so on.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/oaNXWo)

To fix this, the code inside of your `else` block needs to be moved out of the `for` loop entirely.  You need to search the *entire* `vector` to determine if the user already exists or not, and then write that user to the file only if they don't exist at all, eg:

```
void PasswordFile::addpw(const string &newuser, const string &newpassword) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < user.size(); ++i){
        if (user[i] == newuser) {
            cout << newuser << " already exists" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* alternatively:
    if (find(user.begin(), user.end(), newuser) != user.end()) {
        cout << newuser << " already exists" << endl;
        return;
    }
    */

    ofstream file("password.txt", ios::app);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open password file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << newuser << " is being written onto the file\n";
    if (!(file << newuser << " " << newpassword << "\r")) {
        cout << "cannot write to password file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    user.push_back(newuser);
    password.push_back(newpassword);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: On a side note, you should not maintain two separate vectors that are closely related.  Just use a single vector instead, eg:

```
struct UserInfo
{
    string username;
    string password;
};

std::vector<UserInfo> users;

void PasswordFile::addpw(const string &user, const string &password) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < users.size(); ++i){
        if (users[i].username == user) {
            cout << user << " already exists" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    /* alternatively:
    if (find_if(users.begin(), users.end(), [&](const UserInfo &u){ return u.username == user; }) != users.end()) {
        cout << user << " already exists" << endl;
        return;
    }
    */

    ofstream file("password.txt", ios::app);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "cannot open password file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << user << " is being written onto the file\n";
    if (!(file << user << " " << password << "\r")) {
        cout << "cannot write to password file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    UserInfo newuser;
    newuser.username = user; 
    newuser.password = password;
    users.push_back(newuser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remy has done a good job of pointing out the problems you're seeing.

Rather than fixing your loop, I would fix the data structures you're using.

Instead of a pair of vectors, one for user names and one for passwords, I'd start by creating an `std::map` to hold the usernames and passwords:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::string> credentials;
```

A `map` already provides most of what you want, as far as guaranteeing that an entry is unique (each username occurs only once), and lets you check whether an insertion succeeded, so an equivalent of your `addpw` comes down to something like this:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::string> credentials;

void addpw(std::string newuser, std::string newpass) {
    if (credentials.insert({newuser, newpass}).second) {
        std::cout << "Adding new user: " << newuser << "\n";
        file << newuser << " " << newpass << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "User already exists--not adding\n";
    }
}
```

Of course, if you care about security at all, you **really** don't want to store user names and passwords in a plain text file. In fact, you usually don't want to store actual passwords at all--as a bare minimum, you want to salt the password, the hash it with a cryptographic hash algorithm (e.g., SHA-256) then store the salt and the hash, not the password itself. Then to check a user's credentials when they try to log in, you salt what they provide, hash it, and compare the resulting hash to the one you have on file and see if they match.

Now don't get me wrong: that's not the ideal to provide truly maximum security--but at least it's enough to make hackers work a *little* bit to steal your users' credentials.

Comment: In the real-world, this function should handle user updating passwords as well...

Comment: @JinesiYelizati: Well, at least there should be *a* function for updating passwords. Wouldn't necessarily be the same function though.